# Why is a "lookup" feature not propagating from back-end table to linked equivalent in front end?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, lookup

My Access 2010 database application is split into a back end, holding the data tables, and a front end, holding queries and links to the back-end tables.
For my great convenience, almost all of the foreign keys in the data tables have "lookups" defined on them.
That is, the foreign key field has, under `Lookup`, a `SELECT` statement as the attribute for `Row Source`. And there are suitable values for `Bound Column`, `Column Count`, etc.

Under **normal circumstances** (almost every case), those lookups propagate correctly to the linked table in the front end.
That is, upon viewing the linked table, instead of seeing foreign key values, I see the values dictated by the `SELECT` statement.
And when I open the linked table in Design View, the `Row Source` attribute is a copy of the one in the back end.

However, under a **special circumstance** which I don’t understand, one or two of the lookups do not propagate correctly to the linked tables in the front end.
That is, upon viewing the linked table, I see the underlying foreign key values, not the lookup values.
When I open the offending linked table in `Design View`, the `Row Source` attribute is strangely empty.

What setting or action can cause this undesired behavior, and how can I rectify it?
I’ve tried `Compact & Repair`, at both ends, and I’ve refreshed the link via `Linked Table Manager` but it doesn’t fix the problem.

On a probably related note, when I open a linked table in `Design View`, *sometimes* the warning
“Table ‘*table-name*’ is a linked table whose design can’t be modified.” does *not* appear when it should! Why would that be?

Comment: I would have asked over at DBA SE, but the most related question i could find (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160490/how-to-get-lookup-functionality-in-access-when-linking-to-a-sql-table?noredirect=1#comment52790983_19160490) was migrated from there to here!